# Get all combinations of numbers from array returns out of memory error

Tags: php, math

I would like to find all the combinations starting from an array containing several example numbers:

```
$array = [1,10,20,32,12,60,54,90,20,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,22,33,61,62,69,49, ...]; // example 59 numbers
```

I tried various scripts (from anothers SO answer) to find combinations with size 10 such as:

```
function sampling($chars, $size = 10, $combinations = array()) {

        // if it's the first iteration, the first set
        // of combinations is the same as the set of characters
        if (empty($combinations)) {
            $combinations = $chars;
        }

        // we're done if we're at size 1
        if ($size == 1) {
            return $combinations;
        }

        // initialise array to put new values in
        $new_combinations = array();

        // loop through existing combinations and character set to create strings
        foreach ($combinations as $combination) {

            foreach ($chars as $char) {
                $tmp = $combination . $char;
                if ($size == 2) {
                    $tmp .= '.com';
                }

                $new_combinations[] = $tmp;
                // I don't get what you were going to do with this line,
                // but this looks like a logical bug in your code
                //$new_combinations[] = implode(".com", $new_combinations);
            }
        }

        // call same function again for the next iteration
        return $this->sampling($chars, $size - 1, $new_combinations);
    }
```

Or with [Math_Combinatorics](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics):

```
require_once 'Math/Combinatorics.php';
$numbers = [1,10,20,32,12,60,54,90,20,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,22,33,61,62,69,49, ...];
$combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics;
foreach($combinatorics->permutations($numbers, 10) as $p) {
  echo join(' ', $p), "\n"; 
}
```

The error:

> Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 20061356032) (tried to allocate
> 20480 bytes)

I tried to increase the memory:

- php.ini : `memory_limit=-1`
- with script tag `ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");`

Note:

I use `$this->sampling` because function is into class

Comment: You can just achieve all permutations with a single array but the load of sending it to the browser will be huge. Better to make the UI in the browser smart with a next button ;)

Comment: For real it's just a personal tool so the time is not important. can you explaine me how do that?

Comment: If I'm doing the back of my napkin math correctly, `20061356032` is about 18GB which is a lot of memory, probably swap I'd guess. Do you have enough space? Also, taking 10 of just 24 items is 63 trillion permutations or 7 trillion combinations which puts you into terabyte territory.

Comment: How do you calculate this number(63 trillion) @ChrisHaas? So do you think it is impossible?

Comment: I would need the combinations without repetitions example: `[1,2,3]` ok but not `[3,2,1]`. I thought about joining them later but at this point I find it difficult

Comment: So, it is actually nCr you need in mathematical notation and not n!

Comment: There's some [permutation calculators](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutations+%5B24%2C+10%5D) online that you can try to get the amounts.

Comment: Here is to compute for nCr values https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php

Comment: And use nCr will improve my chance to use my script? And if yes how can i apply this math rule?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you plan to use these combinations for? "Just a personal tool" doesn't help us find an approach that fits what you're trying to use this data for.

Comment: I need to find these "unique" combinations from the array I proposed in the example. these combinations will be used for some mathematical tests that do not concern the subject of the question. However, it seems quite clear to me that there is no way to find all possible combinations by removing duplicates without destroying some PCs :)

Comment: It _is_ possible, but should focus on writing the code in such a way that you do not need to store any more than is absolutely necessary. Ideally you would be working only with one permutation and/or combination at once. [Generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) are ideal for this case, and I've previously written a small lib that uses Generators to produce permutations and combinations of given sets: https://packagist.org/packages/wrossmann/pc-iters

Comment: Your code work, i will work for adapt to my result. Please when you have time, post your reply so I approve it. (if you can explain how it works it would be perfect)

Comment: Work for a minuts but show error, i will post here